# Difference between serde2.objectinspector and typeinfo packages

Tags: hadoop, hive

What's the difference between these two packages:

- org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector
- org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo

Is one a newer API? Are they both current, but somehow different? They seem pretty similar to me :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. since the two package both under the specifier serde2, i think both of them are in currently use
2. TypeInfo stores information of a type, and each type with exactly one object to represent it. so, TypeInfo is just a read-only information deal with the object's type(category, type name, etc)
3. Hive has multiple in-memory data format for a given type (e.g. Integer: Integer, IntWritable and LazyInteger). data are stored in object and format/operations stored in object inspector. so a data object and objectinspector represents a data unit, feels like you can deserialize the object use the information provided by objectinspector.

Comment: Yup, that's the way I understand it now too. TypeInfo represent "Hive types" while ObjectInspectors are "(de)serializers" for various representations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ObjectInspectors are used to serialize an object, like suppose you are creating a JSON serde and using a JSON library to convert java objects into JSON and vice versa, then the Hive object you receive is an internal representation of row, this needs to be converted to java object which will be further converted to JSON. for the Hive to JAVA conversion we need objectInspectors eg ListObjectInspector.

Similarly when you deserialize you convert a JSON to a Hive row object, for that we use TypeInfo class eg ListTypeInfo.